Executing DBT model with python code from Azure pipeline
I am trying to execute DBT models with help of python file from Azure pipeline.
With Python, I want to create a list of dbt run command dynamically for those models which failed in last execution of pipeline.
Can anyone point out what us wrong here ?
What I have done so far :
Create dbt_Run.py in dbt :
from dbt.cli.main import dbtRunner, dbtRunnerResult
dbt = dbtRunner()
cli_args = ["run", "--select", "dim_1.sql"]--list of all failed models 
res: dbtRunnerResult = dbt.invoke(cli_args)
 for r in res.result:
     print(f"{r.status}: {r.message}")`

I can execute this useing DBT CLI : py dbt_run.py
But when I try to execute same via Azure pipeline as below, facing error:

- script: |
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install dbt-snowflake --user
    export PATH=$PATH:/to_localfilepath/.local/bin
    cd snowflake_demo 
    - task: PythonScript@0
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'filePath'
        scriptPath: './dbt_run.py'

Error :   py: command not found

You might want to consider the dbt retry command instead.


Error : py: command not found

The error message indicates that the Azure pipeline is unable to find the Python interpreter. Python is not installed, or not is not in the PATH.
Check PythonScript@0 definition:

You can use task UsePythonVersion@0 ahead to download a version of Python to run on an agent, it will add python to PATH by default.
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.7'              # change to your python version
  displayName: 'Use specific Python'

In addition, PythonScript@0 is an individual task, you cannot put it in another script task, use it as a new task. dbt_run.py or dbt_Run.py? it's case sensitive, use the correct name.

is there any way that we can create dependencies between python file execution and script .

DevOps tasks have the dependency by default. If script task failed, the next task PythonScript@0 won't be started unless you have defined custom condition manually. Please refer to the doc for more details.
